# Subproblem size w.r.t Strassen's Matrix Multiplication algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, matrix-multiplication, master-theorem, strassen

I've recently watched a video lecture on Strassen's recursive algorithm for multiplying 2 n x n matrices. The lecture also brought up the Master Method for computing the time complexity of this algorithm. However, when discussing the coefficient b - which from my understanding refers to the factor by which the subproblems decrease in size - it was assigned a value of 2.

My question is: since the 2 n x n matrices are recursively divided into 8 n/2 x n/2 matrices, why is the value of b 2 and not 4?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The *n* in the complexity notation of *O(n<sup>3</sup>)* is the same as the *n* in *n×n*, so the complexity is expressed as a function of the size of one dimension of the matrices.  Since that is halved through each recursion, *b* is 2.

You can see that the naive algorithm really goes through three nested loops of size *n* (the length of one row/column), not *n×n* (the size of the entire matrix), so this seems right.